# removeClass() not working on window resize

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, removeclass

In the jQuery plugin I am writing, I reference the fact that an event has occurred by adding a class to the parent element of the element the event has occurred to. This gets added fine. However, when it comes to removing that class, the class will not remove.

It is a window size change event that triggers the class addition/deletion.

I have created a jsFiddle where you can see when you change the screen width, the class "relocated" applies, but doesn't get removed when the screen is enlarged, like it should.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B8qh3/)

The function where the class is applied and removed:

```
        var init = function() {
            var winW = $(window).width();

            if (winW < settings.breakpoint && !$(el.parentNode).hasClass("relocated")) {
                /* change the order of the item */

                if (settings.targetPosition === "start") {
                    $(el).prependTo(settings.targetContainer[i]);
                } else {
                    $(el).appendTo(settings.targetContainer[i]);
                }

                $(el.parentNode).addClass("relocated");
            } else if (winW >= settings.breakpoint && $(el.parentNode).hasClass("relocated")) {
                /* return the moved item back into the orignal position */
                if (originalLocation.parent) {
                    /* element was a first child */
                    $(originalLocation.parent).prepend(el);
                } else {
                    /* element was not a first child */
                    /* add a line break to preserve inline-block spacing */
                    $(originalLocation.prev).after(el).after("\n");
                }

                $(el.parentNode).removeClass("relocated");
            }
        };
```

Comment: Your logic is failing somewhere, your are removing class and then add it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're removing the class after relocating the element back to its original position. If you move that to before the relocation, it works fine.

```
        } else if (winW >= settings.breakpoint && $(el.parentNode).hasClass("relocated")) {
            // remove the class here
            $(el.parentNode).removeClass("relocated");

            /* return the moved item back into the orignal position */
            if (originalLocation.parent) {
                /* element was a first child */
                $(originalLocation.parent).prepend(el);
            } else {
                /* element was not a first child */
                /* add a line break to preserve inline-block spacing */
                $(originalLocation.prev).after(el).after("\n");
            }

        }
```

If you wait until after you restore the DOM, the parent will be a different element from the one to which you added the class.

You may want to introduce a timer mechanism to reduce the load on the browser. Browsers fire "resize" events *very* aggressively, so doing any significant amount of work in a "resize" event handler can make things really sluggish. What you can do is introduce a timer:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  var timer = null;
  return function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(init, 100);
  };
}());
```

Comment: Yes that makes sense, and thanks for making the suggestion about adding a timer to the resize event, I will implement that